# Python Dynamically creating directory then adding image in directory not working

Tags: python

I am sending the Parameters through postman and which are name, hour, date , image(file)
so the dynamic directory would be assets/img/history/{date}/{name} and the image which I am adding would be named as arrival.jpg

actually directory is creating and arrival.jpg also appearing inside that directory but when I click the image then it showed image is loading but the image never showed up.

here below is my python code

```
@app.route('/receive_data', methods=['POST'])
```

def get_receive_data():

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    json_data = request.form.to_dict()
    try:
        now = datetime.now()
        timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
        image_file = request.files['image']
        image_file2 = request.files['image']

        # Store it in the folder of the know faces:
        file_path = os.path.join(f"assets/allimg/{timestamp}.jpg")
        # file_path = os.path.join(f"assets/allimg2/{timestamp}.jpg")
        image_file.save(file_path) 
        json_data['picture_array'] = f"{FILE_PATH}/{file_path}"  
        connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="faceapp" )
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        user_saw_today_sql_query =\
            f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE date = '{json_data['date']}' AND name = '{json_data['name']}'"
        cursor.execute(user_saw_today_sql_query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        connection.commit()

        # If use is already in the DB for today:
        if result:
           print('user IN')
           image_path = f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/departure.jpg"
           os.makedirs(f"{FILE_PATH}/assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}", exist_ok=True)
           file_path2 = os.path.join(f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/departure.jpg")
           image_file2.save(file_path2)
           json_data['picture_path'] = image_path
            # Update user in the DB
           update_user_query = f"UPDATE users SET departure_time = '{json_data['hour']}', departure_picture = '{json_data['picture_path']}' WHERE name = '{json_data['name']}' AND date = '{json_data['date']}'"

           cursor.execute(update_user_query)

        else:

            image_path = f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/arrival.jpg"
            os.makedirs(f"{FILE_PATH}/assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/", exist_ok=True)
            file_path2 = os.path.join(f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/arrival.jpg")
            image_file2.save(file_path2)

            json_data['picture_path'] = image_path
            insert_user_query = f"INSERT INTO users (name, date, arrival_time, arrival_picture) VALUES ('{json_data['name']}', '{json_data['date']}', '{json_data['hour']}', '{json_data['picture_path']}')"

            cursor.execute(insert_user_query)

    except pymysql.DatabaseError as error:
          print(error)
          
    return jsonify(json_data)
```

the code is inside else part in which image is adding
the part is

```
os.makedirs(f"{FILE_PATH}/assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/", exist_ok=True)
            file_path2 = os.path.join(f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/arrival.jpg")
            image_file2.save(file_path2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First try reading the file and then save it to the required location. Inside your else part, try the below code:

```
image_file2 = request.FILES['image']

file_path2 = os.path.join(f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/arrival.jpg")

with open(file_path2, 'wb+') as f:
    for chunk in image_file2.chunks():
        f.write(chunk)
```

Full code:

```py
@app.route('/receive_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_receive_data():

  if request.method == 'POST':
    json_data = request.form.to_dict()
    try:
        now = datetime.now()
        timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
        image_file = request.files['image']
        image_file2 = request.files['image']

        # Store it in the folder of the know faces:
        file_path = os.path.join(f"assets/allimg/{timestamp}.jpg")
        # file_path = os.path.join(f"assets/allimg2/{timestamp}.jpg")
        image_file.save(file_path) 
        json_data['picture_array'] = f"{FILE_PATH}/{file_path}"  
        connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="faceapp" )
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        user_saw_today_sql_query =\
            f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE date = '{json_data['date']}' AND name = '{json_data['name']}'"
        cursor.execute(user_saw_today_sql_query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        connection.commit()

        # If use is already in the DB for today:
        if result:
           print('user IN')
           image_path = f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/departure.jpg"
           os.makedirs(f"{FILE_PATH}/assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}", exist_ok=True)
           file_path2 = os.path.join(f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/departure.jpg")
           image_file2.save(file_path2)
           json_data['picture_path'] = image_path
            # Update user in the DB
           update_user_query = f"UPDATE users SET departure_time = '{json_data['hour']}', departure_picture = '{json_data['picture_path']}' WHERE name = '{json_data['name']}' AND date = '{json_data['date']}'"

           cursor.execute(update_user_query)

        else:

            image_path = f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/arrival.jpg"
            os.makedirs(f"{FILE_PATH}/assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/", exist_ok=True)

            file_path2 = os.path.join(f"assets/img/history/{json_data['date']}/{json_data['name']}/arrival.jpg")

            with open(file_path2, 'wb+') as f:
                for chunk in image_file2.chunks():
                    f.write(chunk)

            json_data['picture_path'] = image_path
            insert_user_query = f"INSERT INTO users (name, date, arrival_time, arrival_picture) VALUES ('{json_data['name']}', '{json_data['date']}', '{json_data['hour']}', '{json_data['picture_path']}')"

            cursor.execute(insert_user_query)

    except pymysql.DatabaseError as error:
          print(error)
          
    return jsonify(json_data)
```

Comment: It showing IndentationError: expected an indented block on for chunk line

Comment: okay , now it is showing AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'chunks'